# Bash: Access associateive array using for loop variables does not work

Tags: bash, associative-array

I am currently trying to create a whiptail menu to get a key for the associative array and then using a for loop to access the data in the associative array.

This is the bash code I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A backup_source=( [HDD]="Samsung/WD" [Monitor]="/LG/DELL" )


set -x

myArray=()

for key in "${!backup_source[@]}"
do

        myArray+=("$key" "Backup ${backup_source[$key]} to ${backup_destination[$key]}" OFF)

done

BACKUP_CHOICES=( $(whiptail --title "TEST" --checklist "This is just a test" 20 100 10 "${myArray[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) )
#echo "$BACKUP_CHOICES"

for mychoice in "${BACKUP_CHOICES[@]}"
do

        echo $mychoice
        echo ${backup_source[$mychoice]}

done
```

However, the output is:

```
+ backup_source=(['HDD']='Samsung/WD' ['Monitor']='/LG/DELL')
+ declare -A backup_source
+ set -x
+ myArray=()
+ for key in "${!backup_source[@]}"
+ myArray+=("$key" "Backup ${backup_source[$key]} to ${backup_destination[$key]}" OFF)
+ for key in "${!backup_source[@]}"
+ myArray+=("$key" "Backup ${backup_source[$key]} to ${backup_destination[$key]}" OFF)
+ BACKUP_CHOICES=($(whiptail --title "TEST" --checklist "This is just a test" 20 100 10 "${myArray[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3))
++ whiptail --title TEST --checklist 'This is just a test' 20 100 10 Monitor 'Backup /LG/DELL to ' OFF HDD 'Backup Samsung/WD to ' OFF
+ for mychoice in "${BACKUP_CHOICES[@]}"
+ echo '"Monitor"'
"Monitor"
+ echo
```

The `echo ${backup_source[$mychoice]}` is empty.

Expected output would be

```
"/LG/DELL"
```

The funny thing is if I define the variable `$mychoice` in the `for loop` explictly like `mychoice="Monitor"` then it works.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you are using `"Monitor"` as the key instead of `Monitor`. Notice the extra quotes in `+ echo '"Monitor"'`. So your associative array use should be fine, it's the contents of `BACKUP_CHOICES` I think you need to fix.

Comment: Ah perfect. this was the solution. I removed the double quotes and it worked. perfect. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [joanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216427/joanis), the problems were the double quotes as a result of the whiptail return. this code works now:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A backup_source=( [HDD]="Samsung/WD" [Monitor]="/LG/DELL" )


set -x

myArray=()

for key in "${!backup_source[@]}"
do

        myArray+=("$key" "Backup ${backup_source[$key]} to ${backup_destination[$key]}" OFF)

done

BACKUP_CHOICES=( $(whiptail --title "TEST" --checklist "This is just a test" 20 100 10 "${myArray[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) )
echo "${BACKUP_CHOICES[@]}"

for mychoice in "${BACKUP_CHOICES[@]}"
do

        echo $mychoice
        mychoice="${mychoice%\"}"; mychoice="${mychoice#\"}"
        echo "${backup_source[$mychoice]}"

done
```

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that the only difference is the `mychoice="${mychoice%\"}"; mychoice="${mychoice#\"}"` line, in the final loop.